# Find a maximum and minimum in subdirectory (less than 10 seconds with a shell script)

Tags: linux, performance, shell, command, pipeline

I have several files of this type:

```
Sensor   Location              Temp       Threshold
------   --------              ----       ---------
#1        PROCESSOR_ZONE       23C/73F    62C/143F 
#2        CPU#1                30C/86F    73C/163F 
#3        I/O_ZONE             32C/89F    68C/154F 
#4        CPU#2                22C/71F    73C/163F 
#5        POWER_SUPPLY_BAY     17C/62F    55C/131F
```

There is approximately 124630 in several sub-directories
I try to determine the maximal and minimal temperature of PROCESSOR_ZONE
Here is my script at the moment:

```
#!/bin/bash

max_value=0
min_value=50

find $1 -name hp-temps.txt -exec grep "PROCESSOR_ZONE" {} + | sed -e 's/\ \+/,/g' | cut -d, -f3 | cut -dC -f1 | while read current_value ; 
do
    echo $current_value;
done
```

output after my script:

```
30
28
26
23
...
```

My script is not finished and it sets 10 minutes to show all the temperatures.
I think that to arrive there, I have to put the result of my command in a file, sort out it and get back the first line which is the max and the last one the min. But I do not know how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this bit:

```
... | while read current_value ;
do
    echo $current_value;
done
```

just direct the output after `cut` to a file:

```
... > temperatures.txt
```

If you need them sorted, sort them first:

```
... | sort -n > temperatures.txt
```

Then the first line of the file will be the minimum temperature returned, and the last line will be the maximum temperature.

Performance suggestion:

This `find` command runs a new `grep` process on each file. If there are hundreds of thousands of these files in your directory, it will run `grep` hundreds of thousands of times. You can speed it up by telling `find` to run a grep command once for each batch of a few thousand files:

```
find $1 -name hp-temps.txt -print | xargs grep -h "PROCESSOR_ZONE" | sed ...
```

The `find` command prints the filenames out on standard output; the `xargs` command reads these in and runs `grep` on a batch of files at once. The `-h` option to grep means "don't include the filename in the output".

Running it this way should speed up your search considerably if there are thousands of files to be processed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried before to direct the output after cut to a file but the file is nil. I will try for xargs.

Comment: `-exec ... +` does already execute grep with multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is slow, you might want to analyse first which command is slow. Using `find` on for example Windows/Cygwin with a lot of files is going to be slow.

Perl is a perfect match for your problem:

```
find $1 -name hp-temps.txt -exec perl -ne '/PROCESSOR_ZONE\s+(\d+)C/ and print "$1\n"' {} +
```

In this way you do a (Perl) regular expression match on a lot of files at the same time. The brackets match the temperature digits (`\d+`) and `$1` references that. The `and` makes sure print only is executed if the match succeeds.

You could even consider using `opendir` and `readdir` to recursively decend into directories in Perl to get rid of the find, but it is not going to be faster.

---

To get the minimum and maximum values:

```
    find $1 -name hp-temps.txt -exec perl -ne 'if (/PROCESSOR_ZONE\s+(\d+)C/){ $min=$1 if $1<$min or $min == undef; $max=$1 if $1>$max }; sub END { print "$min - $max\n" }' {} +
```

With 100k+ lines of output on your terminal this should save quite a bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

max_value=0
min_value=50

find $1 -name file.txt -exec grep "PROCESSOR_ZONE" {} + | sed -e 's/\ \+/,/g' | cut -d, -f3 | cut -dC -f1 |
{
while read current_value ; do
    #For maximum
    if [[ $current_value -gt $max_value ]]; then
        max_value=$current_value
    fi

    #For minimum
    if [[ $current_value -lt $min_value ]]; then
        min_value=$current_value
    echo "new min $min_value"
    fi
done

echo "NEW MAX : $max_value °C"
echo "NEW MIN : $min_value °C"
}
```